# I2C Usage difference in Arduino and WiringPi

Tags: i2c

I'm using a device through I2C interface and I'm having some issues when the I2C bus fails, I don't know if it fails because an interferance in the cable or just timing issues in the Raspberry over high loads.

The thing is that checking the way this device is used in Arduino and Raspberry there is a difference.

In arduino you use it like this:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x27);
Wire.write(0x80);
Wire.write(75);
Wire.endTransmission();
```

And in RPi you first set the channel into a pointer and then write to it, but never "endTransmission" or "beginTransmission" when you need to send the message.

I just init the i2c channel at the start:

```
dimmer = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x27);
```

And then use this to set the values.

```
wiringPiI2CWrite (dimmer, pin) ;
wiringPiI2CWrite (dimmer, value) ;
```

The problem is that once in a while it stops working, maybe a message got lost in the middle and now those 2 writes never are together waiting for the next byte.
So, is there a difference between the Arduino version and the wiringPi version for this?
is there a way to set the begin and end of a transmission?

The device in question is the Kryda AC Dimmer: https://www.tindie.com/products/bugrovs2012/i2c-4ch-ac-led-dimmer-module/

Comment: Use `int wiringPiI2CWriteReg8 (int fd, int reg, int data);` instead of a pair of writes.

Comment: And... which are you having problems with - the Arduino or the Pi? It's not clear.

Comment: @Majenko the RPi is causing the issues. What you I set on reg? Data is the byte with the 0x80 and the 75 values for example, but what would be the reg?

Comment: "pin" is the register and "value" is the value you are setting in that register.

Comment: If you're using WiringPi on a Raspberry then read this http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/ before deciding which library you're going to switch to when you ditch WiringPi.

Comment: @Dougie - WiringPi seems to be gone already :(  Had to go to the wayback machine to read the wiringpi-deprecated post. This is sad for someone who has used wiringPi through C as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `wiringPiI2CWriteReg8` instead of the raw `wiringPiI2CWrite`:

```
dimmer = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x27);
wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(dimmer, pin, value);
```

This keeps everything together in one neat interface. TBH I am not sure how it differs internally, but it certainly gives you a cleaner interface.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino and Raspberry Pi commands are substantially different.

The Arduino command is sending:

```
start condition
data 0x80 to address 0x27
data 75 to address 0x27
end condition
```

The RPi commands are sending.

```
start condition
data 0x80 to address 0x27
end condition
start condition
data 75 to address 0x27
end condition
```

Frankly I'm surprised the device accepts the Raspberry Pi data as a valid command.

To do the same as the Arduino you would need code such as the following:

```c
char data[]={0x80, 75};

dimmer = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x27);

write(dimmer, data, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks! that's what I wanted to know, yes it's a little bit more difficult to work it around with wiringPi.

I now tried what @Majenko using the wiringPiI2CWriteReg8 function and it works as well..
I will see if using this avoids the issue that sometimes it stopped working.

Comment: The @Majenko command is probably implemented as the SMBus Write byte command (SMBus 2.0 5.5.4).  If so that is equivalent to the code I suggested (which does S Addr Wr [A] i2cReg [A] bVal [A] P in I2C terms).